# Org-babel: using properties as code block header arguments, how to make it work?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am able to execute SQL block with the following:

```
#+NAME:test-1
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :noweb no-export :tangle :engine mssql :cmdline "-S localhost -U SA -P myPassword"
select * from OtherDW.dbo.Supplier_D
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test-1
| Supplier_Id | Supplier_Name |
|-------------+---------------|
|           1 | Walmart       |
|           2 | Amazon        |
```

However, then I moved the header arguments to property in the same file below the above example as follow::

```
* Test
:PROPERTIES:
:engine: mssql
:cmdline: \"-S localhost -U SA -P myPassword\"

#+NAME:using-properties
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :noweb no-export :tangle
select * from OtherDW.dbo.Supplier_D
#+END_SRC
```

Then when I execute the block (C-c C-C), I got the following error:

```
intern(nil)
  (let* ((val (intern engine))) (cond ((eq val (quote dbi)) (let nil (format "dbish --batch %s < %s | sed '%s' > %s" (or cmdline "") (org-babel-process-file-name in-file) "/^+/d;s/^|//;s/(NULL)/ /g;$d" (org-babel-process-file-name out-file)))) ((eq val (quote monetdb)) (let nil (format "mclient -f tab %s < %s > %s" (or cmdline "") (org-babel-process-file-name in-file) (org-babel-process-file-name out-file)))) ((eq val (quote mssql)) (let nil (format "sqlcmd %s -s \"  \" %s -i %s -o %s" (or cmdline "") (org-babel-sql-dbstring-mssql dbhost dbuser dbpassword database) (org-babel-sql-convert-standard-filename (org-babel-process-file-name in-file)) (org-babel-sql-convert-standard-filename (org-babel-process-file-name out-file))))) ((eq val (quote mysql)) (let nil (format "mysql %s %s %s < %s > %s" (org-babel-sql-dbstring-mysql dbhost dbport dbuser dbpassword database) (if colnames-p "" "-N") (or cmdline "") (org-babel-process-file-name in-file) (org-babel-process-file-name out-file)))) ((eq val (quote postgresql)) (let nil (format "%spsql --set=\"ON_ERROR_STOP=1\" %s -A -P footer=off -F \"   \"  %s -f %s -o %s %s" (if dbpassword (format "PGPASSWORD=%s " dbpassword) "") (if colnames-p "" "-t") (org-babel-sql-dbstring-postgresql dbhost dbport dbuser database) (org-babel-process-file-name in-file) (org-babel-process-file-name out-file) (or cmdline "")))) ((eq val (quote sqsh)) (let nil (format "sqsh %s %s -i %s -o %s -m csv" (or cmdline "") (org-babel-sql-dbstring-sqsh dbhost dbuser dbpassword database) (org-babel-sql-convert-standard-filename (org-babel-process-file-name in-file)) (org-babel-sql-convert-standard-filename (org-babel-process-file-name out-file))))) ((eq val (quote vertica)) (let nil (format "vsql %s -f %s -o %s %s" (org-babel-sql-dbstring-vertica dbhost dbport dbuser dbpassword database) (org-babel-process-file-name in-file) (org-babel-process-file-name out-file) (or cmdline "")))) ((eq val (quote oracle)) (let nil (format "sqlplus -s %s < %s > %s" (org-babel-sql-dbstring-oracle dbhost dbport dbuser dbpassword database) (org-babel-process-file-name in-file) (org-babel-process-file-name out-file)))) (t (let nil (error "No support for the %s SQL engine" engine)))))
  (let* ((result-params (cdr (assq :result-params params))) (cmdline (cdr (assq :cmdline params))) (dbhost (cdr (assq :dbhost params))) (dbport (cdr (assq :dbport params))) (dbuser (cdr (assq :dbuser params))) (dbpassword (cdr (assq :dbpassword params))) (database (cdr (assq :database params))) (engine (cdr (assq :engine params))) (colnames-p (not (equal "no" (cdr (assq :colnames params))))) (in-file (org-babel-temp-file "sql-in-")) (out-file (or (cdr (assq :out-file params)) (org-babel-temp-file "sql-out-"))) (header-delim "") (command (let* ((val (intern engine))) (cond ((eq val (quote dbi)) (let nil (format "dbish --batch %s < %s | sed '%s' > %s" ... ... "/^+/d;s/^|//;s/(NULL)/ /g;$d" ...))) ((eq val (quote monetdb)) (let nil (format "mclient -f tab %s < %s > %s" ... ... ...))) ((eq val (quote mssql)) (let nil (format "sqlcmd %s -s \"   \" %s -i %s -o %s" ... ... ... ...))) ((eq val (quote mysql)) (let nil (format "mysql %s %s %s < %s > %s" ... ... ... ... ...))) ((eq val (quote postgresql)) (let nil (format "%spsql --set=\"ON_ERROR_STOP=1\" %s -A -P footer=off -F \"  \"  %s -f %s -o %s %s" ... ... ... ... ... ...))) ((eq val (quote sqsh)) (let nil (format "sqsh %s %s -i %s -o %s -m csv" ... ... ... ...))) ((eq val (quote vertica)) (let nil (format "vsql %s -f %s -o %s %s" ... ... ... ...))) ((eq val (quote oracle)) (let nil (format "sqlplus -s %s < %s > %s" ... ... ...))) (t (let nil (error "No support for the %s SQL engine" engine))))))) (let ((temp-file in-file) (temp-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name " *temp file*")))) (unwind-protect (prog1 (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (insert (let* (...) (cond ... ... ... ... ...)) (org-babel-expand-body:sql body params) (if (string= engine "sqsh") "\ngo" ""))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (write-region nil nil temp-file nil 0))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))) (org-babel-eval command "") (let ((--params result-params)) (if (member "none" --params) nil (if (or (member "scalar" --params) (member "verbatim" --params) (member "html" --params) (member "code" --params) (member "pp" --params) (member "file" --params) (and (or (member "output" --params) (member "raw" --params) (member "org" --params) (member "drawer" --params)) (not (member "table" --params)))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*"))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn ...) (and ... ...)))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*"))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn ... ... ...) (and ... ...))))))))
  org-babel-execute:sql("select * from OtherDW.dbo.Supplier_D" ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params) (:result-type . value) (:results . "") (:exports . "code") (:session . "none") (:cache . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no-export") (:tangle)))
  org-babel-execute-src-block(nil ("sql" "select * from OtherDW.dbo.Supplier_D" ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params) (:result-type . value) (:results . "") (:exports . "code") (:tangle) (:noweb . "no-export") (:hlines . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" "using-properties" 11012 "(ref:%s)"))
  org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
  call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
```

It looks like that the property :engine: took no effect?

What does it take to have the property values effective for header-arguments?

I tried to re-open the file, and do C-c C-c at the top of the file ro refresh the property settings.

But I did found that the following way would work:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql :engine mssql :cmdline -S localhost -U SA -P myPassword
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [sqsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqsh) and org-version 9.1.12, I connect to an mssql server with

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (require 'ob-sql)
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((emacs-lisp . t)
     (sql . t)))
#+END_SRC

#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql :session mysessionname :engine sqsh
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :database MyDbName :dbhost MyDbHost :dbuser sa :dbpassword MyPassword
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :exports results

#+BEGIN_SRC sql
  SELECT top 3 * FROM users;
#+END_SRC
```

In a property drawer, that would be

```
* Heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args:sql: :session mysessionname :engine sqsh
  :header-args:sql+: :database MyDbName :dbhost MyDbHost :dbuser sa :dbpassword MyPassword
  :header-args:sql+: :exports results
  :END:
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the prefix `:header-args:` and the properties termination `:END:`:

```
* Test
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :engine mssql
:header-args+: :cmdline \"-S localhost -U SA -P myPassword\"
:END:

#+NAME:using-properties
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :noweb no-export :tangle
select * from OtherDW.dbo.Supplier_D
#+END_SRC
```

You can also restrict those to `sql` blocks if you like:

```
* Test
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sql: :engine mssql
:header-args:sql+: :cmdline \"-S localhost -U SA -P myPassword\"
:END:

#+NAME:using-properties
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :noweb no-export :tangle
select * from OtherDW.dbo.Supplier_D
#+END_SRC
```

**Edit**: Added `sql+`, as suggested by Nick.

Comment: I tried the above-mentioned methods, it still did not work.

Comment: I believe you need `...:sql+:...` on the second header-args in order to append it to the first one; otherwise, it overwrites it. See the answer by @unhammer.