# Cannot set R :session in file property for interactive use

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r

I would like all R src blocks in an org file to use the same session interactively and have included a minimal example below. I added the `#+PROPERTY` line as in the manual and ran `C-c C-c` as suggested in the related questions to ensure the property takes effect, but it does not seem to work when trying to run src blocks in an interactive manner (i.e. running `C-c C-c` on the src blocks)

I am unsure what I am missing or misunderstanding. Is it possible to use file-level properties for interactively running src blocks?

[Cannot add general block header arguments in org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51988/cannot-add-general-block-header-arguments-in-org-mode)

[Org-babel: using properties as code block header arguments, how to make it work?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39112/org-babel-using-properties-as-code-block-header-arguments-how-to-make-it-work)

[Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html)

```
#+title: Test
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R:  :session *R*

Load a library in one block

#+begin_src R
library(dplyr)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| dplyr     |
| stats     |
| graphics  |
| grDevices |
| utils     |
| datasets  |
| methods   |
| base      |

Try to use a function from that library in another block

#+begin_src R
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
#+end_src

Executing the above with C-c C-c fails because it cannot find ~%>%~, so the two src blocks must be running in
independent sessions.

Error in mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) : could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: No colon after `header-args:R` - see [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html) : `#+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session *R*`

Comment: Doh.  Thanks NickD, that did it.  If you'd like to make that an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Expanding the comment into an answer]

There should be no colon after `header-args:R`:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session *R*
```

It's true that all those colons are confusing, but they are important, so you might want to get the syntax "into your fingers" so to speak.

- The `PROPERTY` keyword is always followed by a colon.
- The property name is never followed by a colon. In this case, the property name is `header-args:R`.
- The property value *in the case of `header-args`* is a sequence of header args, each of which *starts* with a colon.

In general, property values are arbitrary strings, but `header-args` (either bare or qualified by a language) have stricter requirements.

The [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html) shows an `R` example, but does not quite define the syntax: the property name is `header-args:<LANG>` where `<LANG>` is the same string as the one you use in a `#+BEGIN_SRC ... #+END_SRC` block. So in this case, it should be `header-args:R`.

I'm not sure how Org mode parsed `header-args:R:` - I assume it thought the `<LANG>` component was `R:` and, looking for such source blocks, it did not find any, so the setting was ignored.